# Action Script 3. How to make shadow bottom of the character?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, actionscript, shadow

I'm creating flash game and I need to make shadows bottom of the character and enemy. Here is about 35 animations and each with ~100 frames. So edit every frame and draw shadow is something like impossible.

My character's name is Hero and opponent Enemy. I need to make something like that always bottom of Hero and Enemy shadows will be shown (shadow can be circle or etc). Just when jumping It should re-size (when character/enemy on the air, shadow should be dimmer and smaller).

Is It possible to make something like that?

This is how I declare enemy:

```
public var Enemy:Priesas = new Priesas; //Priesas is instance name of Enemy
```

Hero's template is choosing by clicking buttons:

```
public function selectHero(what:int):void {
    // this is called with correct "what", design yourself. I use array index
    var whatHero:Class = heroes[what]; // get selected hero symbol
    if (Hero && Hero.parent) Hero.parent.removeChild(Hero);
    // clean up previous hero. Drop listeners here, if any
    Hero = new whatHero(); // get new hero
    // process as usual, don't forget to "addChild(Hero)" somewhere
    create_hero();
}

    function choosePlayer(event:MouseEvent):void {
        selectHero(0); // here is set first template for my Hero
        start(event);
        }

     function create_hero()
     {
        addChild(Hero);
     }
```

So declared variables are: `Hero` and `Enemy`

This is simplest code how is set animation for character Hero:

```
if (attack1)
{
            enterFrameHandler();
    Hero.gotoAndStop("attack1");

}
```

I don't know if enough info for you, could you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

Create a MovieClip 'Shadow' which is your shadow of whatever shape you want.
Create another MovieClip 'HeroWithShadow' which will contain both your Hero and Shadow.

```
public function selectHero(what:int):void {
    // this is called with correct "what", design yourself. I use array index
    var whatHero:Class = heroes[what]; // get selected hero symbol
    if (Hero && Hero.parent) Hero.parent.removeChild(Hero);
    // clean up previous hero. Drop listeners here, if any
    Hero = new whatHero(); // get new hero
    // process as usual, don't forget to "addChild(Hero)" somewhere
    create_hero();
}

function choosePlayer(event:MouseEvent):void {
    selectHero(0); // here is set first template for my Hero
    start(event);
}

function create_hero(){
    //create shadow
    var shadow:Shadow = new Shadow();
    //create container that will hold both hero and shadow
    var heroWithShadow:HeroWithShadow = new HeroWithShadow();
    //add both hero and shadow on heroWithShadow
    heroWithShadow.addChild(Hero);
    heroWithShadow.addChild(shadow);
    //bring shadow to the bottom of hero
    shadow.y = Hero.height;
    addChild(heroWithShadow);
}
```

Please note that now in case you want to move the hero horizontally(walk) then update 'heroWithShadow.x' and if you want move hero vertically(jump) then update 'Hero.y'
Let me know if this works.